# React radio button button checked attribute not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I have a react component that resembles a radio button input section. I have the checked attribute on each radio input set to a true or false expression, but it does not end up working when I run it.

Any idea on why the item isn't being lit up when a new item is selected? When I log the expression (console.log), I get the correct result.

My code looks like this:

```js
class MyClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentItem: 1,
          }
    }

    updateCurrentItem = (event) => {
        let key = `${event.currentTarget.id}`;
        this.currentItem = key;
        console.log(!(1 % this.currentItem));
    }

    isOn(id) {
        return (!(id % this.currentItem));
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="iconList">

                <input type="radio" id="one" name="picker" value="one" checked={this.isOn(1)}/>
                <label for="one"><button id={1} onClick={this.updateCurrentItem}>One</button></label>

                <input type="radio" id="two" name="picker" value="two" checked={this.isOn(2)}/>
                <label for="two"><button id={2} onClick={this.updateCurrentItem}>Two</button></label>

                <input type="radio" id="three" name="picker" value="three" checked={this.isOn(3)}/>
                <label for="three"><button id={3} onClick={this.updateCurrentItem}><Three</button></label>

                <input type="radio" id="four" name="picker" value="four" checked={this.isOn(4)}/>
                <label for="four"><button id={4} onClick={this.updateCurrentItem}>Four</button></label>
            </div>
            
            );
        }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `this.state` and `this.setState`. Here's a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-dew-thglz?file=/src/App.js